# Lost VirtualBox Snapshots When Moved to a New Machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I had VirtualBox running on my old Windows Vista machine. I was upgraded to Windows 7 on a new machine, and so I have VirtualBox re-installed fresh. I had copied all my VM's from my old machine to a network location, so that I can copy them all (snapshots included) to my new machine.

I have added all the .VDI's to VirtualBox on my new machine, but the snapshots aren't showing.

I have changed the `Settings > General > Advanced` to point to the location where the snapshots are stored, but still no snapshots showing in VirtualBox.

Is there a way I can link the snapshots back up with their machines?

Comment: What does the downvote mean? Is that a no, you can't link the snapshots back with their machines?

Comment: Did you simply copy the files over, or did you open up those vm's thru Virtual Box's UI (something like open existing vm)? Without directly opening them, VirtualBox wouldn't know which files you want to list. For example, you might have backup versions.

Comment: I have backup VM's, but I did: `New > Add existing HDD > Finish`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking last night, that maybe I need to get the VirtualBox.xml file from my old machine and copy that over. Then I would need to change the drive letters, etc. around and see if that fixes it.

Whilst the System Admin was changing my drives, I was reading how to [Open / Import a Pre-configured File in VirtualBox](http://www.sysprobs.com/open-import-xml-pre-configured-file-virtualbox). And you need to go to: `Machine > Add` and navigate to the `.vbox` that you want to add. When you add it, all the snapshots are included, and if the VM was in a group, it would add it to the group.